# Understanding this proof about measurable function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, measurable-functions

I cannot understand this proof.

> Be $(X, \mathcal{F})$ a measurable space. If $f_n : X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are measurable, then $\sup f_n$ is measurable.

*Proof*

$\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\{x\in X \;:\; \sup_n f_n >  a\} \equiv \bigcup_n \{x\in X \;:\; f_n > a\}$ and this belongs to $\mathcal{F}$.

The inclusion $\supset$ is trivial: $a < f_n(x) \leq \sup_n f_n(x)$.

The inclusion $\subset$ comes by contradiction: if $f_n(x) \leq a$ then also $\sup_n f_n(x) \leq a$. This concludes.

- My question is: how the second inclusion concludes the proof? In what way can I say tha then sup is measurable?

I don't really understand this proof, can someone please explain me this better?

Comment: The sup is the lowest upper bound of all $f_n(x)$ and $a$ is one upper bound. What is the relationship then between sup and $a$?   To the second question: The sets $(a,+\infty)$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R\,.$ It is enough to consider those sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that a function $g$ is Borel-measurable, it suffices to show that the sets $\{x\in X\;:\; g(x)>a\}$, $a\in \mathbb R$, are all measurable. That is, it is enough to consider the preimage of the sets $(a,+\infty]$ through the function $g$.

The proof is trying to show this for $g=\sup_n f_n$. How? They rewrite those sets as union of sets that are already known to be measurable, using the fact that the functions $f_n$ are measurable.